# "Unexpected trailing character" in sublime when trying to edit preferences

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to change my sublime theme/colour scheme and i get 
['unexpected trailing characters'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvoBD.png)

When I try to save the /User/Preferences.sublime-settings with this config

```
{
    "theme": "Afterglow-green.sublime-theme",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Afterglow/Afterglow.tmTheme"
}

{
    "tabs_small": true
}
```

I can't work out why I would be getting that message?

Comment: @Smandoli Can you please elaborate, I don't see any trailing characters?

Comment: What happens if you remove the two curly braces in the middle, so it's three lines in one set of curly braces?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your settings files in Sublime (all of them) need to be valid [JSON](http://json.org). Yours should be as follows:

```js
{
    "theme": "Afterglow-green.sublime-theme",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Afterglow/Afterglow.tmTheme",
    "tabs_small": true
}
```

Note that everything is enclosed in one (and only one) outer dictionary, denoted by curly braces `{}`. There should also be a comma `,` at the end of every key: value pair, *except* for the last line. If there is only one line, don't use a comma.

Just out of interest, what is the `"tabs_small"` setting for? It's not one of Sublime's default settings.

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is correct, however this prompt can also occur during application startup.

If this error occurs when you're starting Sublime, navigate to `C:/Users/{Your User}/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User` and open `Plain text.sublime-settings`.

The issue with JSON can be resolved here.