# What does “Unexpected trailing character” mean in this Sublime Text error message?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Just downloaded Sublime Text 3 but there are some problems. I don't know what I did wrong.

[image: Error Dialog]

Comment: Fix the file that the error message is telling you about. Select `Sublime Text > Preferences > Key Bindings` to open the key bindings, and then fix the file in the right hand pane. It's broken at Line 1, column 51.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unexpected trailing character" in sublime when trying to edit preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443710/unexpected-trailing-character-in-sublime-when-trying-to-edit-preferences)

Comment: Thank you so much !